# should pkgutil completely remove Andy Emulator

Tags: uninstall, package-management

I want to completely remove Andy Emulator. It had a pkg file though which it created `Andy.app` in Application folder. Should I use `pkgutil` to completely remove it or deleting the `Andy.app` from Application folder should completely remove it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this twice already, might as well post my "uninstall" steps (for OS X).

As of December 2016 (based on Andy_v46.2.74.108_112_OSX), Andy's install package contains 3 packages: Andy, VirtualBox, and VirtualBox's startup & kexts.

****** Friendly reminder: VirtualBox is a popular free VM from Oracle/Sun. Only remove VirtualBox and its related files if you don't want it and it's not being used by other application(s). ******

**1) Review package metadata using Terminal:**

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info net.andyroid.andy.player.osx
```

...showing files placed in /Applications/Andy.app

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts
```

...showing files placed in /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox
```

...showing files placed in /Applications/VirtualBox.app

virtualbox and vboxkexts should have the same "**install-time**" as andy, otherwise they exist on your system for other reasons and might not warrant the removal.

**2) (Optional) Review installed files using Terminal:**

```
$ pkgutil --only-files --files net.andyroid.andy.player.osx
$ pkgutil --only-files --files org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts
$ pkgutil --only-files --files org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox
```

**3) Once you have confirmed the file locations, delete them using Terminal or Finder (additionally-found user files also listed):**

Andy:

```
/Applications/Andy.app
~/Library/Application Support/Andy
~/Applications/Andy
~/Documents/Andy
~/Library/Preferences/net.andyroid.andy.player.osx.plist
```

VirtualBox:

```
/Applications/VirtualBox.app
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
```

All of these files should add up to well over 2GB for a lightly-used Andy. You might end up with some other leftover plists in ~/Library/Preferences, generally nothing to fuss about.

**4) Finally, remove the receipts using Terminal:**

```
$ sudo pkgutil --forget net.andyroid.andy.player.osx
$ sudo pkgutil --forget org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts
$ sudo pkgutil --forget org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox
```

All done.